# CSS floating text Bar

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#navbar { position: relative; margin: 3px; }
#navbar ul { padding: 0; margin: auto; background: #f0f0f0 url(../images/1px.png) repeat-x 0 -441px; padding: 4px 0 4px 0; }
#navbar li { display: inline; margin-right: 80px; }
#navbar li a { font-family: EqualSansDemo; font-size: 1.6em; color: #555555; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; }   
#navbar li a:hover { color: #0071e4; }
```

And it's will be like that:
[image]

All I need to do is:

[image]

I really tried many of things and waste three hours without any success... I think it's easy but I'm not good with CSS. Any idea please?

Comment: Building a good CSS menu is a difficult task, not something you're going to be able to put together in a couple hours unless you've got some crazy CSS skills. I'd recommend searching for a good third-party control - there are dozens, if not hundreds of good ones out there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9Cr/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a `Suckerfish Dropdown` what you'll have to do is this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Forum
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Some link</li>
            <li>Another link</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

By default of course the children shouldn't be shown so add in your CSS:

```
.children{display:none;}
```

And when the forum element is hovered you should show them, so:

```
li:hover .children{display:block;}
```

Of course you'll need to add some position styling so they're nicely below the forum element and don't break your design. So make sure you take the children class out of the flow with `position:absolute;`

You can read more about suckerfish dropdowns here: http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns

Comment: you beat me to it :) .. here is a fiddle example i made http://jsfiddle.net/2zbTY/2/

Comment: user2019515 @Mortalus Thank you very much for your help :)